# Plugin on wordpress for SEO

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress.org for my blog and want to make it optimized for the search engines like google and bing. Please tell me Which is the best plugin on wordpress.org for SEO?

Comment: here is good example how to [do it][1]

Comment: please check Google webmaster tool help https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291?hl=en

Comment: do some effort and research with google: https://www.google.com/search?site=webhp&source=hp&q=best+seo+plugin+for+wordpress&oq=best+seo+plu&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i20j0l9.998752.1001432.0.1002940.12.10.0.0.0.0.493.3362.0j1j3j3j3.10.0....0...1c.1.32.hp..9.3.945.Ss4qJRF0dYc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `Yoast` :

this one is good for **SEO**

Download link : http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-seo.1.4.22.zip

Plugin Link : http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

thanks

Comment: if you like my post then you can also vote up. thanks for accepting. :)